# How to correct Error: message on website Twitter Feed

Tags: plugins, twitter

I'm receiving a `Error: Twitter did not respond. Please wait a few minutes and refresh this page` message on my website at www.toan.ca. This has been going on for a few days and i would like to know what i need to do to correct so my Twitter feeds begin appearing in my website again. Any support you can offer would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It could be: a plugin, your theme, some code, twitter, your server. Without more details how is anyone supposed to answer this.

Comment: I bet you use some plugin or hack which is no longer compatible with Twitter API.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Wordpress plugin, uninstall it and reinstall it.

If you're using a custom HTML widget, grab the Twitter embed code again, and paste it over the top of the widget HTML code.